# Fourier transform and lebesgue integral

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ be the function with $f(x) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\mid x \mid^2)$. Show that the fourier transform of $f$ is given by $\hat f = (\sqrt{2 \pi})^d f$.

The fourier transform is given by $\hat f (\xi ) := \displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) \exp(-i\xi \cdot x)\ \mu(dx)$.

I would like to start with looking at the case $d = 1$ but I dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Gaussian integral---complete the square up in the exponential to get $(2\pi)^{d/2} e^{-\|\xi\|^2/2}$. Standard result on multivariate Gaussians (and no need to worry about Lebesgue).

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- (x-i \xi)^2/2}dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- x^2/2}dx$

Answer (score 0):

For $d=1$, we have $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ and therefore (remember that $(i\xi+x)^2=-\xi^2+2i\xi x+x^2$)
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\hat{f}(\xi) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-1/2(2i\xi x + x^2)} {\rm d}\mu(x) \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-1/2((i\xi+x)^2+\xi^2)} {\rm d}\mu(x) \\
& = f(\xi) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(i\xi+x)^2/2} {\rm d}\mu(x) \\
& =f(\xi) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2/2} {\rm d}\mu(y) \\
& = \sqrt{2\pi} f(\xi).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

It's pretty similar for $d>1$.

Comment: How do you know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- (x-i \xi)^2/2}dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{- x^2/2}dx$

Comment: Change variable and the contribution from the ends of the contour (which gets shifted up or down) is negligible.

Comment: How do I continue for $d=2$ and so on?

Comment: For any $d\geq 1$ you will get $$\hat{f}(\xi)=f(\xi)\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{-|y|^2/2} {\rm d}\mu(y)$$ which is just $\hat{f}(\xi)=(2\pi)^{d/2} f(\xi)$.

Comment: Actually the fourth equality requires complex analysis which is not allowed in this task.